# compatible erlang and rabbitmq rpm

Tags: linux, erlang, rabbitmq

I am trying to install compatible erlang and rabbitmq RPM's. I don't have external network connectivity so using external repositories is not an option, I have to manually download the RPM's then try to install them. When I try to install these RPM's via YUM I see some dependency issue with the rabbitmq RPM I have chosen.

What are two compatible rabbitmq and erlang RPMS for RHEL6 or CentOS6

```
rabbitmq-rpms]# yum install erlang-20.1.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm rabbitmq-server-3.6.12-1.el6.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
Proxy connection failed: 504
This system is not registered with RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
You can use rhn_register to register.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Examining erlang-20.1.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: erlang-20.1.2-1.el6.x86_64
Marking erlang-20.1.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Marking rabbitmq-server-3.6.12-1.el6.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package erlang.x86_64 0:20.1.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package rabbitmq-server.noarch 0:3.6.12-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: socat for package: rabbitmq-server-3.6.12-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rabbitmq-server.noarch 0:3.6.12-1.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package erlang.x86_64 0:20.1.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

**Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    rabbitmq-server-3.6.12-1.el6.noarch from /rabbitmq-server-3.6.12-1.el6.noarch**

Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                    Version                         Repository                                             Size
======================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 erlang                           x86_64                  20.1.2-1.el6                    /erlang-20.1.2-1.el6.x86_64                            31 M
Skipped (dependency problems):
 rabbitmq-server                  noarch                  3.6.12-1.el6                    /rabbitmq-server-3.6.12-1.el6.noarch                  5.4 M

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total size: 31 M
Installed size: 31 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

When I try to install these I see this dependency problem.

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
        rabbitmq-server-3.6.12-1.el6.noarch from /rabbitmq-server-3.6.12-1.el6.noarch
```

I am also running this OS

```
cat /etc/*release*
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
cat: /etc/lsb-release.d: Is a directory
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.7 (Santiago)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.7 (Santiago)
cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:6workstation:ga:workstation
```

Architecture

```
uname -a
2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Sep 10 13:42:16 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

comparability matrix found here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html

Comment: You might not get a very quick response to this here simply because the Erlang community on StackOverflow is pretty small (and attendance comes in waves). Try asking on the [erlang-questions mailing list](http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-questions) as well. Also, watch out -- the StackOverflow nazis are already trying to close-vote this question out of existence (which I find totally unhelpful and ridiculous -- usually we are spared that sort of nonsense in smaller tags like `erlang` -- but whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing Erlang first, then RabbitMQ. Also, try using `rpm` instead of `yum`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Ill just add to the fact that I found comparability matrix for erlang and rabbitmq releases here https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html